# select an object from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

Here is small dataset which is representative of a larger dataset in a live app -

```
const data = [
            { id: 23, bucket: '12/31/2020' },
            { id: 24, bucket: '3/28/2021' }, 
            { id: 25, bucket: '7/14/2021' }
        ];
```

There is a use case whereby it's necessary to select one of the objects in the `data` array.  For instance, if the object with `id` 24 is to be selected then the required output needs to be
`{ id: 24, bucket: '3/28/2021', status: 'active' }`

Here is what I've tried:

```
const result = data.filter(o => o.id == 24).map(o => ({ id: o.id, bucket: o.bucket, status: 'active' }));
```

However, this is outputting the object as a single object within an array like so
`[{ id: 24, bucket: '3/28/2021', status: 'active' }]`

While another step could be added, `result[0]`, it seems like there should be a way to modify how the code is written for `result` to get the desired outcome on the first pass.  How can this be achieved?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array#find` to find the exact object then add another property `status` along with the other properties with the help of spread operator `...`:

```js
const data = [{ id: 23, bucket: '12/31/2020' }, { id: 24, bucket: '3/28/2021' }, { id: 25, bucket: '7/14/2021' }];
const getData = (id) => ({...data.find(o => o.id === id), status: "active"});
console.log(getData(24));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find` instead of `.filter` to return an item or null (if not found).

Answer (score 0):

map always returns array, check the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map .

Extract the mapped object out from array.

Comment: Yeah, I had checked the docs for `.map()` and knew that it returned an array.  I just didn't know that `.find()` was what to use instead of `.filter()`.

Comment: Ahh! I think the best way to check the documentation first. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array You can find so many useful functions available many from ES6 and above. Also a good idea to check libraries such as lodash https://lodash.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = data.find(({id}) => id === 24)
```